# Class to return

Tags: java

This is the expected output:

```
This Book  
title: The God and the Sword,  
 year of publication: 1975,  
 read: false  
This Book  
title: The God and the Sword,  
 year of publication: 1975,  
 read: true  
This Book  
title: The Light of Spirind,  
 year of publication: 1960,  
 read: false  
The book has now been read: true
```

This is the code that I currently have, I need to write a class named Book. Could someone help me out here please? I am confused with how the first book has a title and year and then the second doesn't have a year provided.

```
class Test{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      int year = 1975;  
      String title = "The God and the Sword"; 

      Book b1 = new Book(title, year);  
      System.out.println(b1);  
      b1.setRead(true);  
      System.out.println(b1);  

      title = "The Light of Spirind";  
      Book b2 = new Book(title);  
      System.out.println(b2);  
      b2.setRead(true);  
      System.out.println("The book has now been read: " + b2.isRead());
   }
}

class Book{

   Book(String title, int year){
      System.out.println("title: " + title + ", " + "year of publication: " + year + ", " + "read: " + setRead);

   }
}
```

Comment: "I am confused with how the first book has a title and year and then the second doesn't have a year provided." Well yes, your current code won't compile, because you don't have a `Book(String)` constructor.

Comment: add another constructor: `public Book(String title){...} `

Comment: Since your desired output does include a year for that book, it seems that your `main` is incorrect and it should be using the constructor that has both title and year.

Comment: I would have thought that the description of the book should be returned from a `toString()` method, not printed from the constructor.

Comment: I think you should first add the methods for the `Book` class so the `main` method is compilable. Then you can write the actual contents of the methods so the results match the expected output.

Comment: If you are just learning java i suggest you to start by learning the basic concepts first and "bang your head" on these excercises by yourself before asking on Stackoverflow. Have you tried compiling and running this code first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** thing I noticed Book constructors are the main issue.

Your first constructor has two parameters `title` and `year`.

`Book b1 = new Book(title, year);`

But in the second constructor has one parameter `title` and you have missed the `year`. That's why you didn't get `year`.

`Book b2 = new Book(title);`

You can correct it by editing the above statement from the below statement.

`Book b2 = new Book(title, year);`

**Second** thing you try to print object like `System.out.println(b2);` without implementing `toString()` method.

Please try following code. You can get the expected output without directly using the `Book()` constructor.

```
class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Book b1 = new Book();
      b1.setYear(1975);
      b1.setTitle("The God and the Sword");
      System.out.println(b1);
      b1.setRead(true);
      System.out.println(b1);

      Book b2 = new Book();
      b2.setTitle("The Light of Spirind");
      b2.setYear(1960);
      System.out.println(b2);
      b2.setRead(true);
      System.out.println("The book has now been read: " + b2.isRead());
   }
}

class Book {

   private boolean read;
   private int year;
   private String title;

   public boolean isRead() {
      return read;
   }

   public void setRead(boolean read) {
      this.read = read;
   }

   public int getYear() {
      return year;
   }

   public void setYear(int year) {
      this.year = year;
   }

   public String getTitle() {
      return title;
   }

   public void setTitle(String title) {
      this.title = title;
   }

   Book() {

   }

   public String toString() {
      return "This Book\ntitle: " + getTitle() + ",\n " + "year of publication: " + getYear() + ",\n " + "read: " + isRead();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class `Book` should have two constructors, one accepting both title and year and one accepting only title. A more complete `Book` class is the following:

```
class Book {
    private String title;
    private int year;
    private boolean read;

    public Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Book(String title, int year) {
        this.title = title;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public boolean isRead() {
        return read;
    }

    public void setRead(boolean read) {
        this.read = read;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add single parameter constructor and check as follows


class Test{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      int year = 1975;  
      String title = "The God and the Sword"; 

      Book b1 = new Book(title, year);  
      System.out.println(b1);  
      b1.setRead(true);  
      System.out.println(b1);  

      title = "The Light of Spirind";  
      Book b2 = new Book(title);  
      System.out.println(b2);  
      b2.setRead(true);  
      System.out.println("The book has now been read: " + b2.isRead());
   }
}

class Book{

   Book(String title, int year){
      System.out.println("title: " + title + ", " + "year of publication: " + year + ", " + "read: " + setRead);

   }

Book(String title){
      System.out.println("title: " + title + "read: " + setRead);

   }
}
```